# Dictionary of different value types into pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary mapped out as:

```
{
   "TopKey":{
      "Key1":"Dictionary",
      "Key2":"String",
      "Key3":None,
      "Key4":"String"
   }
}
```

And would like to map this out as as a pandas dataframe as

| TopKey | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key1 | Dictionary |
| Key2 | String |
| Key3 | None |
| Key4 | String |

I've been looking into documentation and the closest I've found was being able to do something like:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict["TopKey"]).T.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "TopKey"}).transpose()
```

But that explodes the df into a 4 by 4 matrix. Is this due to resetting the index which is causing the dictionary to explode the records out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct "one-shot" way to my knowledge, here is another approach:

```
key = 'TopKey'
pd.Series(sitevar[key]).rename_axis(key).to_frame('Value').reset_index()
# or
# pd.Series(sitevar[key], name='Value').rename_axis(key).to_frame().reset_index()
```

output:

```
  TopKey       Value
0   Key1  Dictionary
1   Key2      String
2   Key3        None
3   Key4      String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(sitevar).reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "TopKey", "TopKey": "Value"})
```

Output:

```
  TopKey       Value
0   Key1  Dictionary
1   Key2      String
2   Key3        None
3   Key4      String
```